# Separate logic from logging via template method pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, template-method-pattern

May I use this template method pattern for separate logic from logging and exception handling or it is "bad practice"?

For example I have this code:

```
public abstract class Parent {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

public void eat() {
    try {
        doEat();
    } catch (SomeException1 e) {
        log.debug("some text");
        throw new CustomException1();
    }
}

protected abstract void doEat();

public void sleep() {
    try {
        doSleep();
    } catch (SomeException2 e) {
        log.debug("some text");
        throw new CustomException2();
    }
}

protected abstract void doSleep();
}
```

And my child class:

```
public class Child extends Parent {
@Override
protected void doEat() {
    //some logic
}

@Override
protected void doSleep() {
    //some logic
}}
```

I would not have different implementations of methods `doEat()` and `doSleep()`.

I want to know whether it's worth it and is it 'bad practice' or not.

Comment: Logging is a cross-cutting concern, and as such, is typically handled using [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pattern solves the problem you are having, and you are confident it won't cause more problems later, I don't see any issue.

My personal preference here would be for a Decorator pattern. In the "Template" version, where `Child` extends `Parent`, the logging behaviour isn't really separate from the logic, it's just hidden. The only benefit is that it's reusable in multiple subtypes of `Parent`. For them to be truly separate would mean you could change either of them, independently, without the client needing to know. This is how a "Decorator" version might work:

```
public class Thing implements MyBehaviour {
    @Override
    public void eat() {
        //some logic
    }
}
```

Then, for the logging:

```
public class LoggingThing implements MyBehaviour {
    public MyBehaviour delegate;

    public LoggingThing(MyBehaviour delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void eat() {
        try {
            delegate.eat();
        } catch (MyException e) {
            // extra behaviour
        }
    }
}
```

Now the logging behaviour is completely separate from the "eat" behaviour. You can have a `MyBehaviour` that logs, you can have a `MyBehaviour` that doesn't log, and you can have a `MyBehaviour` that does any other thing you want it to do. The client never needs to know which one it has.

[Prefer association over inheritance.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)